# Why does projection WKT differ between osr.SpatialReference and gdalinfo

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, well-known-text, epsg

I am writing a simple geotiff using the GDAL python bindings, but the projection WKT reported by `gdalinfo` differs from the source. The script

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy


# Create synthetic data
raster = numpy.zeros((512, 512), dtype=numpy.uint8)
raster[256, 256] = 1
top_left = (100000, 200000)
pixel_size = 30

output_fn = 'test.tif'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
geotiff = driver.Create(output_fn, 512, 512, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
src_geotran = [top_left[0], pixel_size, 0,
               top_left[1], 0, -pixel_size]
geotiff.SetGeoTransform(src_geotran)

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(3413)
srs_wkt = srs.ExportToPrettyWkt()
print(srs_wkt)

geotiff.SetProjection(srs_wkt)
geotiff.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
geotiff = None
```

produces the WKT

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3413"]]
```

Whereas the WKT from gdalinfo is

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3413"]]
```

Notably, the latitude_of_origin and central_meridian show as 0 in gdalinfo, when they should be 70 and -45 respectively.

Tested with Python 2.7.8, GDAL 1.11.1, Numpy 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me, since the projection parameters were not correctly stored or read when reopening (I can't tell which is correct). No errors were raised, and Set / Get / Import methods return a 0 (= good) status, so there are no signals of any errors.

You can add this bug to [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/). If you need a User ID, [it is from here](http://www.osgeo.org/osgeo_userid/). It's also good practice to see if this bug is already listed, but it can be difficult to search for this kind of bug.

Here is a boiled down version of what you are seeing, tested with GDAL 1.11.1:

```
import difflib
from osgeo import gdal, osr
gdal.UseExceptions()
osr.UseExceptions()

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(3413)

# Use a virtual file system
fname = '/vsimem/tmp.tif'
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds = drv.Create(fname, 1, 1)
assert ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt()) == 0

# Close and re-open
ds = None
ds = gdal.Open(fname)
srs_out = osr.SpatialReference()
assert srs_out.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjection()) == 0

# Show differences
print('Differences in PROJ.4')
print(''.join(difflib.ndiff(
    [srs.ExportToProj4() + '\n'],
    [srs_out.ExportToProj4() + '\n'])))

print('Differences in WKT')
print(''.join(difflib.ndiff(
    srs.ExportToPrettyWkt().splitlines(True),
    srs_out.ExportToPrettyWkt().splitlines(True))))

ds = None
gdal.Unlink(fname)
```

The differences in the PROJ.4 output are more critical in my opinion than the WKT.

```
Differences in PROJ.4
- +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
?                               -         ^^^
+ +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
?                                        ^

Differences in WKT
  PROJCS["WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",
      GEOGCS["WGS 84",
          DATUM["WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                  AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
-         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
+         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
?                             +
-             AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
-         UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
+         UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
?                                         +
-             AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
      PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
-     PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
?                                    -
+     PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
-     PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
?                                  ^^^
+     PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
?                                  ^
      PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
      UNIT["metre",1,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
-     AXIS["X",EAST],
-     AXIS["Y",NORTH],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","3413"]]
```

Comment: Much obliged. Filed [Ticket 5889](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5889).